# Nvidia Control Panel not working after installing CUDA Toolkit 8.0

Tags: cuda, installation, gpu, nvidia

I am new to CUDA Development. I installed CUDA Toolkit 8.0 on my laptop running Windows 10 home and has a GTX 960M. Before Installing CUDA Toolkit, the context menu on desktop (right-click on desktop) used to have an option to access Nvidia Control Panel. And there also used to be system tray icons for accessing GeForce experience and GPU Activity status icon.
But after Installing CUDA Toolkit, these icons and options are no longer visible. And when I try to launch the Nvidia control panel from the System Control Panel, an error dialog box appears stating - "**Nvidia Display Settings are not available. You are not currently using a display attached to Nvidia GPU.**"
I don't understand what this means. **Did I mess-up the CUDA Toolkit Installation? Do I have to re-install the Display Drivers and the CUDA Toolkit?**

**Note:** During the installation, I deselected the Display Driver, GeForce Experience and PhysX from the options because I already had their latest up-to-date versions installed on the system.

Comment: I have GTX 1060 and windows 10 installed on my desktop. One week ago I installed CUDA Toolkit 8.0 using the following [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#axzz4VphaeM00) and it works all correctly, include the NVIDIA Control Panel. I sujest you to uninstall gpu driver and CUDA Toolkit and reinstall them without uncheck the display Driver, GeForce Experience and PhysX from the options during the installation.

Comment: @sgira Did you do a custom or express installation of the CUDA Toolkit.?

Comment: I did a custom installation but I just left everything the way it was. So  think It's like I did an express installation. I have just read in [lNVIDIA CUDA INSTALLATION GUIDE FOR MICROSOFT WINDOWS](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/secure/prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Windows.pdf?autho=1484520687_8551b8d1b156d68d892b7829404f8d6c&file=CUDA_Installation_Guide_Windows.pdf) at start of chaper 2.2 two things that might interest you, see the link.

Comment: @sgira Did you install Display Driver after installing CUDA.?

Comment: I had already installed the last Display Driver before install CUDA Toolkit 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nvidia drivers provided with CUDA toolkit are really old; newer Nvidia drivers are available from the website. The same goes with NSight Visual Studio plugin.

I generally install CUDA toolkit first, then update the Drivers and Nsight through separate installation.

You just need to reinstalled the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I don't think the order of installation should be a problem. As mentioned here: [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#install-cuda-software). The Driver and toolkit must be installed for CUDA to function, but nothing about the order.

Comment: @Sarvex At the moment the NVIDIA GPU drivers that I installed from CUDA Toolkit 8.0 is the lastest, in accord to the website.

Comment: @Savrex This [link](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2136/kw/how%20to%20install%20cuda%20toolkit/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ4NDU2Mzk2OS9zaWQva1lrMURQOG4%3D) tells that first Display Driver, then CUDA toolkit and finally CUDA SDK should be installed.

Comment: @harshatech2012 CUDA is released once an year, Nvidia Drivers once a week. So when CUDA toolkit was released, it contained the latest drivers (but that was two months ago)

Comment: @Sarvex Thanks..!! Worked for me. I did the following.
- Uninstall CUDA and the Nvidia Display Drivers (if needed use DDU). 
- Install CUDA with all the components (custom installation --> CUDA+PhysX+Graphics Driver+GeForce Experience)
- After CUDA installation restarts the computer.
- Then install the latest Display Drivers (custom installation --> Graphics Driver+GeForce Experience+PhysX)